# Flink 1.12 timeWindowAll/timeWindow operators deprecation

Tags: apache-flink

I want to update my flink application 1.11.0 -> 1.13.2
My codebase stopped compiling due to depreciation of `StreamExecutionEnvironment.setStreamTimeCharacteristic`,`timeWindow()`

Some code

```
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
      env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(20,10000L))
      env.getConfig.setGlobalJobParameters(parameterTool)
      env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime) #1
      env.getConfig.setParallelism(parallelism)

    val packetSource = env
      .addSource(
        new FlinkKinesisConsumer[String](s"packet-stream-name", new SimpleStringSchema, consumerConfig))
      .map(json => read[MyCaseClass](json))
      .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy
        .forBoundedOutOfOrderness[MyCaseClass](Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .withTimestampAssigner(new PacketWatermarkGenerator))
      .timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(2))  #2
      .process(new OrderPacketWindowFunction)

    val heartbeatEvents = packets
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(4)) #3
      .process(new HeartbeatWindowFunction)
```

Since i have `env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)` config, looks like i need to do following

1. remove the redundant config - `env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)`
2. replace `.timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(2))`  -> `.windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(2)))`
3. `.timeWindow(Time.seconds(4))` -> `.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(4)))`

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove the redundant config - `env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)`
2. replace `.timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(2))` -> `.windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(2)))`
3. replace `.timeWindow(Time.seconds(4))` -> `.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(4)))`